# Problems making POST request on Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask, heroku, post, axios

So I'm working on a web app developed with `Flask` and deployed on `Heroku`. I need to make a `POST` request and receive a response from the server. I managed to get it working with a `Python` script, but I need to **"translate"** the code to `Javascript` so I can use it properly on my website.
The `Flask` app on `Python`:

```js
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Index Page"
@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    data = request.form.get('data')
    if data == None:
        return 'Got None'
    else:
        # model.predict.predict returns a dictionary
        prediction = makePrediction(data)
    return json.dumps(str(prediction))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Working `Python` code making the `POST` request:

```py
def main():
    PARAMS = {'data':'sample text'}
    response = requests.post(url='https://textgenerator123.herokuapp.com/predict?', data=PARAMS)
    print(response.text)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to use `Axios` to make the `POST` request with `Javascript` with the following code:

```js
axios.post('https://textgenerator123.herokuapp.com/predict?', {
  data: 'sample text'})
  
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

But the console returns **"Got None"**. So the web app receives the request, but with data as `Null` for some reason. I'm new to `Javascript` and would be grateful if anyone tried to help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about the network? What is the response? if it's in the 200, the post should have gone through.
The "got none" might be the response from the post response body. I think you should check the network request in your dev tools to see what the response was.

Answer (score 0):

If you use   `data = request.get_json()` instead of `data.form` it should work since this parses the incoming data as you send it through axios: `{ data: 'sample text'}`. The [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request) explain the methods available for requests, form data is probably not what you want to use in this case.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Index Page"
@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
      data = request.get_json()
    if data == None:
        return 'Got None'
    else:
        # model.predict.predict returns a dictionary
        prediction = makePrediction(data)
        print(prediction)
    return json.dumps(str(prediction))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```